# Multiple docker containers removed when trying to remove one

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a project where distributed nodes are in docker containers on a docker network.

In total I have nodes 1, 3, 4, 5, 7.

I control these nodes from a CLI process on my own machine. For example I can write `kill 7` to stop & remove docker node with id 7. Only problem is that around 5% of the time it results in stopping and removing node 7 along with a random other node.

This `kill 7` goes to `stopAndRemoveDocker()` function written below:

```
import { exec } from 'child_process';
import { Promise as BluebirdPromise, resolve } from 'bluebird';

const asyncExec:Function = BluebirdPromise.promisify(exec);

export const stopAndRemoveDocker = (id:number) => {
  console.log(`Stopping and removing docker container with id: ${id}`);
  exec(
    `docker container stop $(docker container ls -a --filter name=dst2-${id}) ; docker container rm $(docker container ls -a --filter name=dst2-${id})`,
    () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`Docker container ${id} removed`);
      }, 2000);
    },
  );
};
```

From the console.logs() I always get:

```
Stopping and removing docker container with id: 7
Docker container 7 removed
```

And for debugging docker I found out with command `sudo journalctl -fu docker.service` that docker API did indeed receive 2 remove commands?

```
Apr 12 13:00:14 TRT-89TFQ73 dockerd[1306]: time="2021-04-12T13:00:14.920333711+03:00" level=info msg="Container 73a3736c3eaa2067bc85c544f3eb1f0fef8b76c4b5a1ff5c456f51c88356f9a0 failed to exit within 10 seconds of signal 15 - using the force"
Apr 12 13:00:14 TRT-89TFQ73 dockerd[1306]: time="2021-04-12T13:00:14.920341516+03:00" level=info msg="Container c351d715f095edae678fd1cca30699c4279260bf0e4004f8ada91ca56dea635f failed to exit within 10 seconds of signal 15 - using the force"
Apr 12 13:00:14 TRT-89TFQ73 dockerd[1306]: time="2021-04-12T13:00:14.930696262+03:00" level=info msg="Container 73a3736c3eaa2067bc85c544f3eb1f0fef8b76c4b5a1ff5c456f51c88356f9a0 failed to exit within 10 seconds of signal 15 - using the force"
Apr 12 13:00:14 TRT-89TFQ73 dockerd[1306]: time="2021-04-12T13:00:14.930696077+03:00" level=info msg="Container c351d715f095edae678fd1cca30699c4279260bf0e4004f8ada91ca56dea635f failed to exit within 10 seconds of signal 15 - using the force"
Apr 12 13:00:14 TRT-89TFQ73 dockerd[1306]: time="2021-04-12T13:00:14.973277455+03:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=c351d715f095edae678fd1cca30699c4279260bf0e4004f8ada91ca56dea635f module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Apr 12 13:00:14 TRT-89TFQ73 dockerd[1306]: time="2021-04-12T13:00:14.973950861+03:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=73a3736c3eaa2067bc85c544f3eb1f0fef8b76c4b5a1ff5c456f51c88356f9a0 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
```

Comment: If you already know the container name, you can pass it directly to `docker stop` and `docker rm`; you don't need the `docker container ls` call.  You also might consider using a native SDK like [Dockerode](https://github.com/apocas/dockerode) rather than the rather dangerous shell commands you show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker container stop $(docker container ls -a --filter name=dst2-7)` sometimes gives:

```
d1c103e8bec8
dst2-7
```

Sometimes gives:

```
c8697cd40c94
1
dst2-7
```

This is due to me not adding `-q` to the command and it printing the whole line.

Then `docker stop` parses the line (space delimited) and part of it e.g. `1 minute ago` creates a command `docker stop 1`, which is a valid command, since it matches `14db5c496cab` container hash